# Changed API-server manifest file, but changes aren't implemented

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am adding the flag `--cloud-provider=aws` to `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` and `kube-controller-manager.yaml`. When I describe the pods I can see that they pick up the change and are recreated, however the flags have not changed.

Running on Centos7 machines in AWS. I have tried restarting the Kubelet service and tried using `kubectl apply`.

Comment: Are your running EKS nodes?

Comment: We are running k8s the hard way, on ec2 instances using kubeadm.

Comment: which version of kubernetes are you using?

Comment: Kubernetes V1.15.0

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways to achieve this. But seems like you have choosen the DynamicKubeletConfig way but you didn't configure [DynamicKubeletConfig](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/11/dynamic-kubelet-configuration/)! To do live changes to your cluster you need to *enable* **DynamicKubeletonfig** first then follow the steps [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reconfigure-kubelet/)

Another Way [[Ref]](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1464#issuecomment-518178729)
TL;DR (do this at your own risk!)
Step 1: `kubeadm config view > kubeadm-config.yaml`
Step 2: edit kubeadm-config.yaml to add your changes [[Reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/control-plane-flags/) for flags ]
Step 3: `kubeadm upgrade apply --config kubeadm-config.yaml`